# Join dataframes, retaining column names

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have the following 3 data frames, each of which has columns with names. I want to combine them and retain the column names. When I use the patch I found for combining dataframes, it drops that name on any dataframes that don't have at least 2 columns. How can I retain the names?

```
x<-data.frame(mean(1:10))
names(x)[names(x) == 'mean.1.10.'] <- 'var.name'
y<-data.frame(1:4)
names(y)[names(y) == 'X1.4'] <- 'var.name2'
z<-data.frame(matrix(1:10,5,2))
names(z)[names(z) == 'X1'] <- 'var.name3'
names(z)[names(z) == 'X2'] <- 'var.name4'

list_datf <- list(x, y, z)
n_r <- seq_len(max(sapply(list_datf, nrow)))
NEW <- do.call(cbind, lapply(list_datf, `[`, n_r, ))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include `drop = FALSE` in the indexing step so that the things you're binding together retain all of their dimensions. I couldn't figure out a way to do this by passing `drop = FALSE` as an extra argument to `[`, so I resorted to using an anonymous function  instead.

```r
NEW <- do.call(cbind, lapply(list_datf, function(x) x[n_r, , drop = FALSE]))
```

Alternatively, you could convert your components to tibbles, which (unlike data frames) never drop "unneeded" dimensions:

```r
NEW <- do.call(cbind, lapply(list_datf, function(x) tibble::as_tibble(x)[n_r, ]))
```

If you want to go full tidyverse:

```r
library(dplyr)
list_datf %>% purrr::map(~ tibble::as_tibble(.)[n_r, ]) %>% bind_cols()
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm getting an error with this>>>     Error: unexpected input in "NEW <- do.call(cbind, lapply(list_datf, \"

Comment: what version of R? `\(x)` is fairly new. I'll switch back to the old syntax.

Comment: Working, thank you! Why was it just dropping names for 1-column dataframes though?

Comment: That's how R does it. See `?"["` and search for `drop`